# Master-detail using bindings with TWO NSTableViews

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I have a list of objects displayed in an NSTableView (bound to an NSArrayController). When you select an object in that list I want to show a detail view in a second NSTableView. My object has an array property. I can't figure out how to wire the bindings for this. binding to NSArrayController's selection doesn't work, as that's a single object, and NSTableView expects to be bound to an array...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a second `NSArrayController` and bind its contents to the first controller using a keypath of `selection.<name of your object's array property>`.

So, if your first table view is displaying objects of class `Person` and your `Person` class has a `children` property, you would bind the second array controller to `selection.children`.

You need a separate array controller for each array that you want to manage in a table view.

Comment: Thanks! this was very helpful. Now my `selection` property doesn't seem to be updating when the selection changes, but that's a new problem

Comment: @KennyWinker did you manage to solve the selection issue? I believe I have the same, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190299/nscollectionview-master-detail-binding-configuration