# NSCollectionView Master detail binding configuration

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing, nsarraycontroller, nscollectionview

I have the following models in my application.

- `Board`, holds a NSMutableArray property `lists` of type `List` below
- `List`, holds a NSArray property `cards` of type Card below
- `Card`, has a NSString property `name`

The relationship is thus Board --> to-many List --> to-many Card

I have a NSCollectionView based master-detail interface,
where I want to display Boards in the master and its corresponding Lists+Cards in the detail
view.

The master interface is fine, the elements `Board` are displayed nicely.

## Bindings are setup like so:

BoardArrayController -> bound to File's owner

- ** Model key path: boards
- ** Mode: Class
- ** Item prototype: Board View Item

ListArrayController -> bound to BoardArrayController.

- ** Controller key: <strike>arrangedObjects</strike> selection
- ** Model key path: lists
- ** Mode: Class
- ** Item prototype: List View Item

CardArrayController -> bound to ListArrayController

- ** Controller key: <strike>arrangedObjects</strike> selection
- ** Model key path: cards
- ** Mode: Class

The master collection view has the Content bound to BoardArrayController

- ** Controller key: arrangedObjects

The detail collection view has the Content bound to the BoardArrayController

- ** Controller key: selection
- ** Model key path: lists

## View item prototype

Any view element in the prototype views (those that are added with the NSCollectionView) have the following info

- ** Bound to: Board View Item (master) or List View Item (detail)
- ** Model key path: representedObject followed by .property

## Problem

The detail interface is not updated when I click a board in the master view. I expect a new set of lists+cards being displayed. It is only the one loaded at startup which is being displayed.

## Questions

Is this a NSCollectionView selection problem or a binding problem?

*Hint:* I think it's a binding problem. Because it works, if in my controller I observe `masterView.selectionIndexes` and bind an IBOutlet to `detailedView`. Then in `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` I manually call `detailedView:setContent:`.

*Edit:* updated setup description in accordance to the answer in [Cocoa Bindings for hierarchical model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228532/cocoa-bindings-for-hierarchical-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got an answer from the cocoa-dev mailing list (thanks Willeke).

**Solution**

The master view selectionIndexes is bound to BoardArrayController. With Controller Key `selectionIndexes`.

The detailed view content should then be set to ListArrayController and Controller Key Path `arrangedObjects`