# Cocoa Bindings for hierarchical model

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing

I have a NSCollectionView based master-detail interface,
where I want to display Boards in the master and Lists+Cards in the detail view.

`Board`, holds a `NSMutableArray` property `lists` of type List
`List`, holds a `NSArray` property `cards` of type Card
`Card`, has a `NSString` property `name`

The relationship is thus Board --> to-many List --> to-many Card

The master interface is fine.

The detail interface gets populated with corresponding Lists' titles 
for a Board. Within the detail interface I also want to populate a NSPopupButton with the 
cards for every list.

Problem: the NSPopupButton is empty.

`Output: [<__NSArrayI 0x60000007b240> addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] is not supported. Key path: name`

So after reading KVO, KVC and the Bindings documentation I am not sure if I need to do manual KVO for this sort of hierarchical model. Also the output hints that the name property is not KVC/KVO compliant, but it's just a NSString?

Do you suggest using an NSTreeController for this?

Bindings are setup like so:

BoardArrayController -> bound to File's owner

- ** Model key path: boards

ListArrayController -> bound to BoardArrayController

- ** Controller key: arrangedObjects
- ** Model key path: lists
- ** Mode: Class

CardArrayController -> bound to ListArrayController

- ** Controller key: arranged Objects
- ** Model key path: cards
- ** Mode: Class

The NSPopupButton has

- Controller key for Content: arrangedObjects
- Controller key for Content Value: arrangedObjects and model key path: name

Suggestions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand properly, in the master interface, the user selects a Board. Then, the detail interface should show the selected Board's lists. If so, the `ListArrayController` should be bound to `BoardArrayController`, controller key **`selection`** (not `arrangedObjects`), model key path `lists`.

Similarly, the `CardArrayController` should be bound to `ListArrayController`, controller key `selection`, model key path `cards`. Although it's not clear to me if the user has to first select a List and then sees a pop-up with that List's cards or if the pop-up is present in each item in the second collection view. If that's the case, then you'll need a separate array controller for each item, which is easiest if the item view is in a separate NIB.

Comment: The list name and its cards are shown directly in the detail view. Why  is that I have to use `selection` and not arrangedObjects?

Comment: Your modifications, in combination with @mikeD in NSCollectionViewItem works. Now trying to apply the same and fill the content for a NSTableColumn, it doesn't work. Instead, if I use the `CardArrayController` and Controller Key: selection and M.K.P name I can select rows, but they don't contain any text.

Answer (score 1):

If each `list` is the `representedObject` for each view item in the collection view, then you can populate each popupButton with a `readonly` NSArray property dependent upon the `cards` array that is in each `list`. In the `List` class add arrangedCards as a property.

```
- (NSArray *)arrangedCards
{
    return [[self valueForKey:@"cards"] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
      [self arrangedCardsSortDescriptors]];
}
```

Use the sort you want for the popup. This arranges by `name`.

```
- (NSArray *)arrangedCardsSortDescriptors
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:
      @"name" ascending:YES];
    return @[sortByName];
}
```

Bind the Content of the popup to the NSCollectionViewItem.

Model Key Path is `representedObject.arrangedCards`.

Use `representedObject.arrangedCards.name` as the Content Values.